# Adding 1 more column to grouped by dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I currently have these 2 dataframes(before/after)

Before:

```
timestamp   cnt t1  t2  hum wind_speed  is_holiday  weather year    month   day
0   2015-01-04 00:00:00 182 3.0 2.0 93.0    6.0 0   broken clouds   2015    1   4
1   2015-01-04 01:00:00 138 3.0 2.5 93.0    5.0 0   clear   2015    1   4
2   2015-01-04 02:00:00 134 2.5 2.5 96.5    0.0 0   clear   2015    1   4
3   2015-01-04 03:00:00 72  2.0 2.0 100.0   0.0 0   clear   2015    1   4
4   2015-01-04 04:00:00 47  2.0 0.0 93.0    6.5 0   clear   2015    1   4
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
17337   2016-12-31 19:00:00 493 9.0 6.0 82.0    17.0    0   cloudy  2016    12  31
17338   2016-12-31 20:00:00 465 8.5 6.5 84.5    13.0    0   cloudy  2016    12  31
17339   2016-12-31 21:00:00 474 8.0 6.0 87.0    12.0    0   cloudy  2016    12  31
17340   2016-12-31 22:00:00 587 8.0 6.0 90.0    12.0    0   cloudy  2016    12  31
17341   2016-12-31 23:00:00 697 8.0 5.0 87.0    18.5    0   cloudy  2016    12  31
```

After:

```
timestamp   cnt
0   2015-01-04  9234
1   2015-01-05  20372
2   2015-01-06  20613
3   2015-01-07  21064
4   2015-01-08  15601
... ... ...
722 2016-12-27  10842
723 2016-12-28  12428
724 2016-12-29  14052
725 2016-12-30  11566
726 2016-12-31  11424
```

So the point is that i deleted all necessary columns and summed up cnt values( that was made to delete hours from dates and merge them into single index containing all cnt's)

But there is also a column called 'is_holiday' that has 0 if no holiday during this day or 1 if holiday during this day. Indexes of this column show 1 or 0 each hour if holiday is during THIS day. I want to make my 2nd dataframe have 3rd column 'is_holiday' that has 1 or 0.

How do i remake my 1st dataframe to also have is_holiday in 2nd dataframe to make it easier find out if 'cnt' which means 'bicycles rent this day' is higher during holiday days or not.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

path2 = r'C:\Users\bossd\OneDrive\Документы\pipirka.csv'
df2 = pd.read_csv(path2) 
df2 = df2.groupby(df2["timestamp"].dt.date)["cnt"].sum().reset_index() # Making 2nd dataframe
x = df2.loc[df2['timestamp'].str.startswith('2015'), 'timestamp']
y = df2.loc[df2['timestamp'].str.startswith('2015'), 'cnt']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.groupby` + `.agg`:

```py
df = (
    df.groupby(df["timestamp"].dt.date)
    .agg({"cnt": "sum", "is_holiday": "first"})
    .reset_index()
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    timestamp  cnt  is_holiday
0  2015-01-04  573           0
```

Comment: Hey pal, sorry for asking so long after your answer on my previous question, but how and why did you put ["cnt"].sum() right after df.groupby(df["datetime"].dt.date) how do they connect? I've been thinking about this for a long time

Comment: @krmbla When you do `df.groupby(df["timestamp"].dt.date)['cnt'].sum()`, then you do grouping only on one column (`sum` in this case). `df.groupby(df["timestamp"].dt.date)` returns a groupby object (see the doc). You can do `for idx, g in df.groupby(df["timestamp"].dt.date): print(idx, g)` for example too see it better.

Comment: so groupby does grouping with everything said after df.groupby and doesn't have to be in brackets? Also after printing(idx,g) I got my full dataframe without anything being sorted out and this dataframe also has ugly index numbers that change while rolling down

Comment: @krmbla With `print(idx, g)` you should get individual dates in `idx` and individual dataframes (`g`) that conforms to this date. I'd recommend to *investigate* `pd.groupby` on smaller example dataframe (not big one)

Comment: The dataframe is printing weirdly, any ideas how to fix it, since i get the second right part of the dataframe printed with new indexes

Comment: @krmbla You probably want `print(idx, '\n', g, '\n\n')`